# SQL - updating primary keys in a table

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL table that uses a form's ID from a web app as the foreign key.  When the app user first creates a request, we assign that request a temporary ID before another service updates our DB to have the real ID.  I created a logging utility to track user and service actions for our app, but I need to create a stored procedure to update all records in my table with the temp ID to be the real ID.  Since it is a foreign key, I know I can't call UPDATE, so I thought of creating a temp table with all the rows with the temp ID, Inserting those details back into my main table with the real ID instead, and then deleting all records with the tempID, and then dropping my temp table. 
 Something like:

```
@tempID VARCHAR(20), @realID VARCHAR(20)
--create a temp table
CREATE TABLE #tempTable
( fieldA VARCHAR(max), fieldB int, id VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #tempTable
  SELECT fieldA, fieldB, id FROM myTable WHERE id=@tempID

INSERT INTO myTable
  SELECT fieldA, fieldB, @realId FROM #tempTable

DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id=@tempID

If(OBJECT_ID('#tempTable') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #tempTable
End
```

Is this the right way to go about it?

Comment: First which technology is this mysql or sql-server they are two different things.

Comment: @Brad Sorry!  This is a SQL stored procedure

Comment: @user3334871, then you should tag the question with sql-server. MySQL is a different DBMS product.

Comment: @user3334871, you can update the primary key; no need to delete and insert.

Comment: @DanGuzman hmm, I was told by someone that you can't call UPDATE to cvhange the primary key.  I'll look into that then, lol

Comment: You can update a PK, you can not update an identity, though a lot of times they are the same thing.

Comment: @user3334871, to add on to what Brad said, some use the term primary key and identity interchangeably. They are completely different things.

Comment: Sounds like you want to update the auto increment identity of the table? If that's the case I would add a column for PK that you can update. Then the PK constraint will stop any non unique attempts.

Comment: @briskovich Sorry, I was typing PK when I actually meant its a FK, so I can't perform an UPDATE ON it.  I will update my question, as it now seems WHOLLY unclear

Answer (score 0):

Will your DBA allow you to change the foreign key so that it will cascade the update?  If so you can just update your primary key and it will automatically update all the foreign key values as well.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.yourtable ADD CONSTRAINT
    FK_yourkey FOREIGN KEY
    (
    yourcolumn
    ) REFERENCES dbo.yourprimarytable
    (
    yourcolumn
    ) ON UPDATE  CASCADE
```

If you can do this, you'll have to drop and recreate the keys, there is no way to change the keys with an ALTER statement.